# understanding the ssh login using PKI

Tags: ssh, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption, pki

I have generated a keypair(public and private) and copied over the public key over to a remote server, `ssh-copy-id` the public key and disabled password based login. Now I can ssh into the machine without providing a passphrase.

I've been looking around for the protocol or message exchanges that might happen on the occasion that I ssh into the remote machine I have been looking around but could not find articles that describe how exactly the identity is confirmed in such a situation. I understand PKI, and Diffie-Hellman at a very high level but I'm not able to get the big picture about what exactly happens what i ssh into the remote machine.

Could someone explain/link me to articles that do the same? Thanks!

Comment: Surely this is all in the RFC(s)?

Comment: sure thanks, rfc4252 seems to be the one

Answer (score 2):

From the RFC:

> With this method, the possession of a private key serves as
>   authentication.  This method works by sending a signature created with
>   a private key of the user.  The server MUST check that the key is a
>   valid authenticator for the user, and MUST check that the signature is
>   valid.  If both hold, the authentication request MUST be accepted;
>   otherwise, it MUST be rejected.  Note that the server MAY require
>   additional authentications after successful authentication.

If you use verbose on ssh you can see, the client offeres a message on login, that is signed with your private key. If you use multiple keys, it will send them one by one. The server checks, if the signature is valid with the help of your public key. If the signature is valid and the public key is known to the server it will grant access. If not, your client will try the next or if none is left it will deny access.

Comment: Thanks! By signature do you mean a digital signature(signed public key)?

Comment: I suggest the server sends the key, that is signed by the user, but I cannot verify this. And yes I mean digitally signed.

Comment: No, first of all the server checks if the public key offered is configured for the given user. Then the signature is over the following data: `string session identifier, byte SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST, string user name ...`, where the session identifier is probably the unique data required for a challenge response protocol. The signature is created using the private key at the client and verified by the public key at the server.